# Parsing WordPress stdClass Data In PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I executed a query in PHP to retrieve data from `wp_options` in my WordPress database table.

The output is as follows:

```
O:8:"stdClass":4:{s:12:"last_checked";i:1517323099;s:8:"response";a:0:{}s:12:"translations";a:0:{}s:9:"no_update";a:3:{s:19:"akismet/akismet.php";O:8:"stdClass":9:{s:2:"id";s:21:"w.org/plugins/akismet";s:4:"slug";s:7:"akismet";s:6:"plugin";s:19:"akismet/akismet.php";s:11:"new_version";s:5:"4.0.2";s:3:"url";s:38:"https://wordpress.org/plugins/akismet/";s:7:"package";s:56:"https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/akismet.4.0.2.zip";s:5:"icons";a:3:{s:2:"1x";s:59:"https://ps.w.org/akismet/assets/icon-128x128.png?rev=969272";s:2:"2x";s:59:"https://ps.w.org/akismet/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=969272";s:7:"default";s:59:"https://ps.w.org/akismet/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=969272";}s:7:"banners";a:2:{s:2:"1x";s:61:"https://ps.w.org/akismet/assets/banner-772x250.jpg?rev=479904";s:7:"default";s:61:"https://ps.w.org/akismet/assets/banner-772x250.jpg?rev=479904";}s:11:"banners_rtl";a:0:{}}s:9:"hello.php";O:8:"stdClass":9:{s:2:"id";s:25:"w.org/plugins/hello-dolly";s:4:"slug";s:11:"hello-dolly";s:6:"plugin";s:9:"hello.php";s:11:"new_version";s:3:"1.6";s:3:"url";s:42:"https://wordpress.org/plugins/hello-dolly/";s:7:"package";s:58:"https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/hello-dolly.1.6.zip";s:5:"icons";a:3:{s:2:"1x";s:63:"https://ps.w.org/hello-dolly/assets/icon-128x128.jpg?rev=969907";s:2:"2x";s:63:"https://ps.w.org/hello-dolly/assets/icon-256x256.jpg?rev=969907";s:7:"default";s:63:"https://ps.w.org/hello-dolly/assets/icon-256x256.jpg?rev=969907";}s:7:"banners";a:2:{s:2:"1x";s:65:"https://ps.w.org/hello-dolly/assets/banner-772x250.png?rev=478342";s:7:"default";s:65:"https://ps.w.org/hello-dolly/assets/banner-772x250.png?rev=478342";}s:11:"banners_rtl";a:0:{}}s:19:"jetpack/jetpack.php";O:8:"stdClass":9:{s:2:"id";s:21:"w.org/plugins/jetpack";s:4:"slug";s:7:"jetpack";s:6:"plugin";s:19:"jetpack/jetpack.php";s:11:"new_version";s:5:"5.7.1";s:3:"url";s:38:"https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/";s:7:"package";s:56:"https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.5.7.1.zip";s:5:"icons";a:4:{s:2:"1x";s:60:"https://ps.w.org/jetpack/assets/icon-128x128.png?rev=1791404";s:2:"2x";s:60:"https://ps.w.org/jetpack/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1791404";s:3:"svg";s:52:"https://ps.w.org/jetpack/assets/icon.svg?rev=1791404";s:7:"default";s:52:"https://ps.w.org/jetpack/assets/icon.svg?rev=1791404";}s:7:"banners";a:3:{s:2:"2x";s:63:"https://ps.w.org/jetpack/assets/banner-1544x500.png?rev=1791404";s:2:"1x";s:62:"https://ps.w.org/jetpack/assets/banner-772x250.png?rev=1791404";s:7:"default";s:63:"https://ps.w.org/jetpack/assets/banner-1544x500.png?rev=1791404";}s:11:"banners_rtl";a:0:{}}}}
```

Here's the formatted data that I unserialized from the initial output above:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [last_checked] => 1517323099
    [response] => Array
        (
        )

    [translations] => Array
        (
        )

    [no_update] => Array
        (
            [akismet/akismet.php] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => w.org/plugins/akismet
                    [slug] => akismet
                    [plugin] => akismet/akismet.php
                    [new_version] => 4.0.2
                    [url] => https://wordpress.org/plugins/akismet/
                    [package] => https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/akismet.4.0.2.zip
                    [icons] => Array
                        (
                            [1x] => https://ps.w.org/akismet/assets/icon-128x128.png?rev=969272
                            [2x] => https://ps.w.org/akismet/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=969272
                            [default] => https://ps.w.org/akismet/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=969272
                        )

                    [banners] => Array
                        (
                            [1x] => https://ps.w.org/akismet/assets/banner-772x250.jpg?rev=479904
                            [default] => https://ps.w.org/akismet/assets/banner-772x250.jpg?rev=479904
                        )

                    [banners_rtl] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [hello.php] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => w.org/plugins/hello-dolly
                    [slug] => hello-dolly
                    [plugin] => hello.php
                    [new_version] => 1.6
                    [url] => https://wordpress.org/plugins/hello-dolly/
                    [package] => https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/hello-dolly.1.6.zip
                    [icons] => Array
                        (
                            [1x] => https://ps.w.org/hello-dolly/assets/icon-128x128.jpg?rev=969907
                            [2x] => https://ps.w.org/hello-dolly/assets/icon-256x256.jpg?rev=969907
                            [default] => https://ps.w.org/hello-dolly/assets/icon-256x256.jpg?rev=969907
                        )

                    [banners] => Array
                        (
                            [1x] => https://ps.w.org/hello-dolly/assets/banner-772x250.png?rev=478342
                            [default] => https://ps.w.org/hello-dolly/assets/banner-772x250.png?rev=478342
                        )

                    [banners_rtl] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [jetpack/jetpack.php] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => w.org/plugins/jetpack
                    [slug] => jetpack
                    [plugin] => jetpack/jetpack.php
                    [new_version] => 5.7.1
                    [url] => https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/
                    [package] => https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jetpack.5.7.1.zip
                    [icons] => Array
                        (
                            [1x] => https://ps.w.org/jetpack/assets/icon-128x128.png?rev=1791404
                            [2x] => https://ps.w.org/jetpack/assets/icon-256x256.png?rev=1791404
                            [svg] => https://ps.w.org/jetpack/assets/icon.svg?rev=1791404
                            [default] => https://ps.w.org/jetpack/assets/icon.svg?rev=1791404
                        )

                    [banners] => Array
                        (
                            [2x] => https://ps.w.org/jetpack/assets/banner-1544x500.png?rev=1791404
                            [1x] => https://ps.w.org/jetpack/assets/banner-772x250.png?rev=1791404
                            [default] => https://ps.w.org/jetpack/assets/banner-1544x500.png?rev=1791404
                        )

                    [banners_rtl] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I am looking to parse the data to get the `slug` value, but I'm not sure how to best parse an `stdClass` object.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: print_r(unserialize($str));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress stores wp_option data as a serialized string. So you need to **unserialize** it:

```
$obj = unserialize($data);
```

**But** you should use `get_option()` function from WordPress - then you will get it automatically unserialized.

To get the slugs of the plugins parse the object like that :

```
foreach($obj->no_update as $plugin){
    $slug = $plugin->slug;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I needed to retrieve this data while not logged into WordPress and I've noticed from some previous testing that WordPress requires you to be logged in to access their functions.

Comment: @frankangelone the functions are accessible without being logged in. It depends where you use them - in what "hooks". But `get_option()` should be available most of the time.

Comment: I see. If I were to use the WordPress functions, it would be outside of the WordPress context.  I would have a separate, standalone PHP file in my root domain folder.

Comment: Then you need to use raw PHP functions. WordPress functions would be available for example in the active theme files like `functions.php`

Comment: I have added the unserialized version of the data as an edit to my original question.  What would you use to get the value of the `slug` key when looping through the results.

Comment: It's not clear from the poorly formatted view but you must use `$obj->slug` to get the corresponding value

Comment: My apologies.  I have formatted the code accordingly.

Comment: I updated the answer with the loop you would use to get the slugs

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks for all of your help.  That's exactly what I was looking for.